# Use Either for retrofit2 response

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I've created a class like this:

```
sealed class Either<out L, out R> {
    //Failure
    data class Left<out L>(val value: L) : Either<L, Nothing>()

    //Success
    data class Right<out R>(val value: R) : Either<Nothing, R>()

    val isRight get() = this is Right<R>
    val isLeft get() = this is Left<L>
}
```

I am using retrofit and I am planning to return this:

```
@GET(__SOMEPATH__)
suspend fun pews(__Whatever__) : Either<Throwable, POJO>
```

But when `Gson` tries to create the object, an exception is thrown:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private com.pew.pew.base.networking.Either() with no args

And also

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class com.pew.pew.base.networking.Either
> ```

Is there any way to encapsulate Error and Result on retrofit response?

### EDIT

Now I have another sealed class

```
sealed class Result<T> {
  data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
  data class Unauthorized(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
  data class Timeout(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
  data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
​
fun <A, B> Result<A>.map(mapper: (A) -> B): Result<out B> {
  return when (this) {
    is Success -> Success(mapper(data))
    is Unauthorized -> Unauthorized(exception)
    is Timeout -> Timeout(exception)
    is Error -> Error(exception)
  }
}
```

And then in my RepositoryImpl I need to define wether it is a Success or an Error. How do I do that? Before I was using a fold, which allowed me to get the Success or Error.

Can I do something like change from `Call<T>` to `Result<T>`?

```
inline fun <reified T> execute(f: () -> Call<T>): ResultWrapper<T> =
        try {
            when (T::class) {
                Unit::class -> f().execute().let {
                    ResultWrapper.Success(Unit as T)
                }
                else -> f().execute().body()?.let {
                    ResultWrapper.Success(it)
                } ?: ResultWrapper.Error(Throwable())
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            ResultWrapper.Network(serverError)
        }
```

But it says 
[image]

Comment: That is not Retrofit's job. That is the job of the repository that calls this Retrofit API, or something else downstream (e.g., a viewmodel converting responses into viewstates). Retrofit's generated API (`pews()`) will throw exceptions; some downstream code of yours will need a `try`/`catch` structure to catch those exceptions. If you want to then wrap those in your `Either` construct, you are welcome to do that.

Comment: But I can not use `Either<Throwable,POJO>` as a result of `pews()` right? Shall I use something like a sealed class that contains Result and Error? Like Result<POJO> and in the repositoryImpl do a flatMap or whatever to returl Result.Success(it) or Result.Failure(Throwable())?

Comment: "But I can not use Either<Throwable,POJO> as a result of pews() right?" -- correct, because nothing can create an instance of that. "Shall I use something like a sealed class that contains Result and Error?" -- the Retrofit API would return `POJO`. The repository could elect to wrap `POJO` or any `Throwable` into an `Either` or some other sealed class. Or, handle that in the viewmodel or other code that consumes the repository. I tend to just use natural exception propagation until I get close to the UI layer (e.g., a viewmodel) before wrapping the exception in something (e.g., a viewstate).

Comment: @CommonsWare Check my edit please.

Comment: If you have `suspend fun pews(): POJO`, then use `Result.Success(api.pews())`, where `api` is an instance of your Retrofit-generated API. Assuming that your other three `Result` states are based on exception types, wrap the `Result.Success(api.pews())` in a `try`/`catch` construct with `catch` clauses that return the other `Result` types.

Comment: Can I do like a convertor from Call<T> to Result<> And then add there the if it's a success or failure? Something like my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201137/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-commonsware).